# Is there a way to conditionally apply annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, cas, playframework-2.3

In my java-play application I have the annotation `@RequiresAuthentication(clientName = "CasClient")` inside my controller.

I only want to authenticate users in my production environment.

How can I apply annotations conditionally?

If the way I'm approaching authentication is wrong, what is the conventional way of doing CAS authentication only on production in a java play application?

Comment: what about that? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide4

Comment: try to use the condition after getting the response or use the annotation after checking whatever you want to! i don't see the problem here

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie if you could provide an example of how I would use an annotation after performing a check, that is exactly what I'm looking for answer wise.

Comment: You are using play-pac4j for authentification, right? Or is RequiresAuthentication your custom annotation?

Comment: @Tijkijiki Yeah pac4j

Answer (score 2):

You could implement **authenticators** to authenticate users. you could you write your authentication logic in your authenticator implementation.

Play already comes with a built in **authenticator** action, which we will extend to add our logic. We will call this authenticator **Secured**.

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;

import models.*;

public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
        return ctx.session().get("email");
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx) {
        return redirect(routes.Application.login());
    }
}
```

We have implemented two methods here. **getUsername** is used to get the **username** of the current logged in user. In our case this is the **email** address, that we set in the email attribute in the session when the user logged in. If this method returns a value, then the authenticator considers the user to be logged in, and lets the request proceed. If however the method returns **null**, then the authenticator will block the request, and instead invoke **onUnathorized**, which we have implemented to redirect to our login screen.
You could implement your own business logic for user verify user.

Now let’s use this authenticator. In Application.java, add the **@Security.Authenticated** annotation with our authenticator to the **index** method:

```
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Application extends Controller {

     @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
      public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render(
         Project.findInvolving(request().username()), 
           Task.findTodoInvolving(request().username()),
            User.find.byId(request().username())
         )); 
     }
}
```

[Refs:Play Implementing Authenticator Example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide4)